# Retrieving all Window classes in WPF by reflection?

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

I have WPF project that I use for test purposes, for every Window I create I add new button in the start window, I want to change this and add the buttons dynamically by reflection, I tried this:

```
public partial class _DynamicWindow : Window
    {
        StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
        public _DynamicWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RetrieveAll();
            Content = stack;
        }

        private void RetrieveAll()
        {
            foreach (var window in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Window)).GetTypes())
            {
                CreateButton(window);
            }
        }

        private void CreateButton(Type window)
        {
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(window) as Window;
            Button btnShow = new Button();
            btnShow.Click += delegate { obj.Show(); };
            btnShow.Content = obj.Name;
            stack.Children.Add(btnShow);
        }
    }
```

but I get this error:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''The invocation of the
>   constructor on type 'WPFTest._DynamicWindow' that matches the
>   specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '6' and
>   line position '9'.'
>
> ArgumentException: Cannot create an instance of
>   <>f__AnonymousType0`1[j__TPar] because
>   Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.

Comment: yes for now, later I will create a boolean AP that will check if I want to add it it to `stack` or not

Comment: `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Window)).GetTypes()` will return all of the types in the assembly where the `Window` type is declared. First, that's not your assembly. Second, that gives you _every_ type in the assembly, not just `Window` subclasses.

Comment: First part of marked duplicate's accepted answer explains how to _correctly_ find all types which derive from another type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create instances of classes inheriting `Window`, not all classes.
Your search should be something like this:

```
var assembly = ...
foreach(var window in assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => typeof(Window).IsAssignableFrom(x)))
...
```